# What is the correct Access Token URI for AWS Cognito and Alexa account linking?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, alexa-skills-kit

I am a bit confused as to how to setup Cognito as a provider for account linking in Alexa. So far in Alexa, I have the following:

**Authorization URL:**

```
https://[domain].auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=[clientID]&redirect_uri=https://pitangui.amazon.com/api/skill/link/[random]
```

This is backed up by the docs for [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html) endpoint. Then I would think that the **Access Token URI** would be following:

```
https://[domain].auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=code&client_id=[clientID]&redirect_uri=https://pitangui.amazon.com/api/skill/link/[random]
```

This endpoint is also in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html). But this does not work, and I also confused as to how Amazon passes the code from the auth endpoint to the token endpoint. I've seen people use:

```
https://pitangui.amazon.com/api/skill/link/[random]?grant_type=code&client_id=[clientID]&redirect_uri=https://pitangui.amazon.com/api/skill/link/[random]
```

Which is the account-linked redirect URI. In the Alexa app and in the Alexa site, I get redirect-mismatch. All the redirects match.

I can get this to work using the implicit flow just fine, but I need to get it to work with the auth code flow so I can have self-refreshing tokens.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got it to work, here is what I had to do:

## Auth Code Flow:

The Alexa Skill configuration page needs the following:

### Account Linking:

**Authorization URL:** https://[your-cognito-domain].auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=[your-client-id]&redirect_uri=https://pitangui.amazon.com/api/skill/link/[vendor-id-amazon-gives-you]&state=[random-string-of-your-choosing]

The docs say that state is optional but I could not get the Auth Code flow to work without it.

**Client Id:** Same as the client id from the Authorization URL. This comes from the App Clients page in Cognito. This was a big gotcha for me, I thought this was random but no, it needs to match the above client id.

**Domain List, Scope:** I did not need these.

**Authorization Grant Type:** Auth Code Grant

**Access Token URI:** https://[your-cognito-domain].auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token?state=[same-string-as-the-one-in-auth-url]

**Client Secret:** This comes from the App Clients page in Cognito.

### Cognito App Client Settings:

**Enabled Identity Providers:** Cognito User Pools

**Callback URL(s):** https://pitangui.amazon.com/api/skill/link/[vendor-id-amazon-gives-you-in-alexa-config-page]

**Sign out URL(s):**https://[your-cognito-domain].auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/logout?response_type=code&client_id=[your-client-id]&redirect_uri=https://pitangui.amazon.com/api/skill/link/[vendor-id-amazon-gives-you]

I am dropping the Implicit Grant here as a bonus:

## Implicit Grant Flow:

**Authorization URL:** https://[your-cognito-domain].auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=[your-client-id]&redirect_uri=https://pitangui.amazon.com/api/skill/link/[vendor-id-amazon-gives-you]

As I said earlier, I did not have to use state here.

**Client Id:** Same as the client id from the Authorization URL. This comes from the App Clients page in Cognito. This was a big gotcha for me, I thought this was random but no, it needs to match the above client id.

**Domain List, Scope:** I did not need these.

**Authorization Grant Type:** Implicit Grant

### Cognito App Client Settings:

**Enabled Identity Providers:** Cognito User Pools

**Callback URL(s):** https://layla.amazon.com/spa/skill/account-linking-status.html?vendorId=[vendor-id-amazon-gives-you-in-alexa-config-page]

**Sign out URL(s):** https://[your-cognito-domain].auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/logout?response_type=token&client_id=[your-client-id]&redirect_uri=https://layla.amazon.com/spa/skill/account-linking-status.html?vendorId=[vendor-id-amazon-gives-you-in-alexa-config-page]

Comment: I really needed this but something I'm not getting, like what is layla.amazon.com and pitangui.amazon.com. Is it random or user-specific?

Comment: @myke_11j That comes from Amazon. You can use any of them, they should all work. I do not know where the names come from though.

Comment: This is the only place on the Internet I have found that describes how to make this work properly.  I'm using Alexa for Business and that added some challenges around documentation and testing.  Can confirm for A4B users that this is a good path to follow!